# PHP and MYSQL supported versions for upgrade

Tags: php, mysql

We are trying to upgrade the PHP website that connects to MYSQL DB. We are trying to use the following version of Apache, PHP,MYSQL and PHPMyadmin

PHP  : 5.6.6
MYSQL  : 5.6
Open SSL:  v1.0.2a
Apache Server  :  2.4.12
PHP MYADMIN  : 4.4.1.1

PHP 5.6.13 is the latest version. New versions are PHP are released very frequently (5.6.9 -->5.6.10 --> 5.6.11 --> 5.6.13).

I am trying to check the PHP compatibility with MYSQL, Apache and PHPMyadmin. Is there any PHP/MYSQL compatibility/supported versions for upgrade.

we are trying to select the correct versions of PHP and MYSQL for the upgrade.

Thanks
Ashok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia: XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP)

Under Components you'll find a list of all components including PHP, apache, MySQL and phpmyadmin with version numbers included, as far as I know, they use the latest stable version of each component so you'll have a good overview of what versions to pick.

EDIT: They use the latest versions that work together, so that should do the trick of finding out what versions to use.